# Rounded Edges Around A Code Block With Remarkable

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Remarkable](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable) is a Markdown to HTML converter. It is, however, able to be customised by passing an array when instantiating the library. Similar to:

```js
var rm = Remarkable('full', {
    key:value,
    key1:value1
});
```

You can convert markdown by calling the library via

```
var html_output = rm.render("### Markdown!");
```

Which would return the following:

> #### Markdown!

However, I cannot figure out how to insert an element tag before the `<code>` tag, which would take the form

`<tag-here><code> [...] </code></tag-here>` Does anyone know how I would do this, since I want to add text highlighting and rounded edges to my html output via CSS for this tag:

```
tag{
    background-color: #444;
    border-radius:2px;
    padding:2px;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, I found that the best way to do this was to add `display: inline-block;` to the CSS. This makes the tag behave a lot like a `<div>` element allowing for rounded edges, highlighting, padding etc.  The finished CSS looks similar to this:

```
tag{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #444;
    border-radius:2px;
    padding:2px;
}
```

Thanks for the views (I guess?)